# Determining convergence of a statistic when sampling

Tags: sampling, convergence

I am attempting to determine the value of some statistic$^{a}$ over some large sample, by iteratively subsampling it and checking for convergence as I do so.

For example, I might pull a batch $\mathcal{B}_i$ from my large sample $\mathcal{S}$, and apply some function $f(\cdot)$ on that sample.  By iteratively doing this, I know that I should be able to get a better picture of what $f(\mathcal{S})$ is (assuming that $\mathcal{B}_i$ is randomly drawn from $\mathcal{S}$) by taking the mean of the different $f(\mathcal{B}_i)$. $^{b}$.

Which leads to my questions:

- How do I know that I have taken enough samples from $\mathcal{S}$ to determine $f(\mathcal{S})$ within some error band and some confidence interval?  The naive answers (either the mean of $f(\sum_i \mathcal{B}_i)$ stops changing very much with increasing $i$, or the variance of $\{f(\mathcal{B}_i)\}$ reaches some threshold value) seem to be fairly sample inefficient.
- How do I appropriately sample $\mathcal{S}$ so that I can find $f(\mathcal{S})$ the most efficiently (assuming that every element I pull from $\mathcal{S}$ has some cost).

---

$^a$ I'm specifically interested in $F_{\beta}$ or precision and recall, so my samples are labeled pairs.  However, I'm trying to make this question fairly generic.

$^b$ Assuming that $f(\cdot)$ is appropriately well behaved for this to be true.